# Using limit values to prove the statement $T(n) = 6n \ln{n} + 12n = o(n^2 )$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, algorithms

$T(n) = 6n \ln{n} + 12n = o(n^2 )$,

I'm wondering what on earth does $o(n^2)$ represent apart from being ever so positive ($n^2$) and what I'm supposed to prove here, exactly. Am I supposed to prove that the left side of the equation is always the right side of the equation, or am I to find the ranges where this holds true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called "little-oh notation". We say that $f(n) = o(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$ iff $f(n)/g(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Here of course the thing that $g(n) \neq 0$ for large $n$ is presupposed.

So to prove that $T(n) = o(n^{2})$ is to prove that 
$T(n)/n^{2} \to 0$. In fact, we have
$$
\frac{T(n)}{n^{2}} = \frac{6n\log n + 12n}{n^{2}} = \frac{6\log n}{n} + \frac{12}{n} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it technically be the limit superior of the absolute value? It's been a while since I saw a proof, but I seem to remember Big-O notation meaning that $\limsup_{n\to a} \left \lvert \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \right \rvert = C < \infty$ where Little-O notation is simply the case $C=0$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, it is another way to say the same thing :).

Answer (score 3):

A function $f(n)$ is said to be $o(g(n))$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$. This is called "Little-o" notation, and it is not so much a "function" as it is a way of representing a property of asymptotic growth. The other big example of this notation is called "Big-O" notation. The definition of that would be $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if and only if there is a constant $C > 0$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = C$.

So this problem wants you to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{T(n)}{n^2} = 0$.

Comment: Wouldn't a constant $C$ not mean $\Omega(g(n))$ rather than $O$? Don't we also need to allow the limit to be $\infty$ to have Big-O?

Comment: Pretty sure $\Omega(g(n)$ means that for some $C_1, C_2$ and for some positive integer $N$, we have for all $n > N$ that $C_1g(n) \leq f(n) \leq C_2 g(n)$. This is a stronger statement than $O(g(n)$ but is similar in many ways. And this problem does have the limit going to infinity, and that is a requirement for this notation.

Comment: Where can I find the definitions of the notations such as $O$ and $o$ ?

Comment: Here is a link to the Wiki page for $O$ (chosen because this is the most well-known of these notations). It also has some information on $o$ and one or two other related concepts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 2):

The relation $T(n) = 6n \ln{n} + 12n = o(n^2 )$ means that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \dfrac{T(n)}{n^2} = 0$$

In this case,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \dfrac{6n\ln{n} + 12n}{n^2} = \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left( \dfrac{6\ln{n}}{n} + \dfrac{12}{n}\right) = 0$$

as desired.